# Как отследить ход выполения js?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Есть большое количество js файлов. Есть ли какой-то быстрый способ (программа) найти строчку кода, например, отвечающую за нажатие кнопки, и отследить цепочку выполнения скрипта?

Спасибо.

Comment: Может помочь какая-нибудь IDE мб, типо PHPStorm

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[Вот тут](http://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome) очень хорошо расписано про отладку скриптов в браузере. Но в любом случае вам нужно понимать, что находится в каждом js-файле, и знать синтаксис языка.

Также нужно помнить несколько правил выполнения js:

1. Js-файлы выполняются друг за другом, если нет [дополнительных атрибутов](http://learn.javascript.ru/script-place-optimize#%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B-async-%D0%B8-defer).
2. Внутри файла в первую очередь выполняются [Function Declaration](http://learn.javascript.ru/function-declaration-expression#%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-function-declaration), а потом уже всё остальное сверху вниз.
3. В целом после прочтения всего [этого учебника](http://learn.javascript.ru/), придёт понимание очень многих вещей в JS.